# Referencing a global variable in forloop from Apache Velocity

Tags: velocity, number-formatting

I am having trouble with having a formatter within a forloop in Apache Velocity.

```
#set( $array = ["10000", "3000", "13.456", "1111.13"] )

<ul>
#foreach( $a in $array) 
  <li>$formatter.print($a)</li>
#end
</ul>
```

This would be evaluated and print the original expression as a string 4 times

```
$formatter.print($a)
$formatter.print($a)
$formatter.print($a)
$formatter.print($a)
```

instead of

```
10,000.00
 3,000.00
    13.456
 1,111.13
```

However it seems to work fine with the formatter outside of the scope from the forloop

```
<p>$formatter.print(123456)</p>
```

This would work as usual

Can anyone helps me figuring out how to reference a property (in this case $formatter) within a for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when one of the following condition is true:

1) The model passed to the velocity does not have the variable "formatter"

2) The method *print* is returning null or it does not exist

3) The method print accepts a parameter of the wrong type. Try to pass Object...

The following code works for me **(notice that I am using an array of double and not any more an array of string)**:

```
package test;

import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
public class VelocityHelloWorld
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Exception
    {
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        ve.init();
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("formatter", new Formatter());
        Template t = ve.getTemplate( "helloworld.vm" );
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge( context, writer );
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

**Velocity:**

```
#set( $array = [10.00 , 20.00, 13.456, 1111.13] )

<ul>
#foreach( $a in $array) 
  <li>$formatter.print($a)</li>
#end
</ul>
```

**Formatter:**

```
package test;

public class Formatter {
    public String print (Object d) {
        String s =  d.getClass().getName() + ": " + d.toString();

        return s;
    }
}
```

The template shows the same behaviour like yours if I substitute in

```
print (Double d)
```

Double with Float.

Long story short... I think that you probably need to check the parameter passed to your method.

Of course I think you should use Double and create the array as a list of double and not as a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try ${myref.doIt($var)} syntax to reference context variable. This ensures Velocity does not parse context names incorrectly within strings.

Comment: What do you mean ? ${formatter.print($a)} ? it doesn't work

Comment: Which one of the print(string) or print(double or float) function exist? Use hardcoded value in a loop to test it also.